# Document.getElementbyID() can't get my <select> element

Tags: javascript, html

FYI, I'm working on a basic web library interface that allows users to add book info and get that info displayed. After some debugging, I notice that my function responsible for taking the book info that people input didn't function as I wanted. To be specific, `document.getElementbyID()` can't seem to select my html `<select>` element even though it could select my input fields with no problems. In addition, it seems that the `bookInfo` variable is empty for some reasons unknown to me.

My CSS, for a more user-friendly design. There's nothing wrong with it, just something to make viewing my preview a bit easier:

```js
let myLibrary = [];

function Book(author,title,pages,readStatus) {
    this.author = author
    this.title = title 
    this.pages = pages 
    this.readStatus = readStatus
}

function addBooktoLibrary(book) {
    myLibrary.push(book)
}

document.querySelector('.new').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.getElementById('add-dialog').showModal()
})

document.getElementById('cancel').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.getElementById('add-dialog').close()
}) 

function displayBook(bookInfo){
    const bookElement = document.createElement('div');
    const buttonDiv = document.createElement('div')
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.innerText = 'Remove'
    bookElement.innerHTML = `Title: ${bookInfo.title}<br> Author: ${bookInfo.author}<br> Pages: ${bookInfo.pages}<br> Status: ${bookInfo.readStatus}`;
    buttonDiv.appendChild(removeButton)
    buttonDiv.classList.add('buttonDiv')
    bookElement.appendChild(buttonDiv)
    bookElement.classList.add('book')
    removeButton.classList.add('remove')
    document.querySelector('.card-container').appendChild(bookElement);
}

function processInfo(){
    let bookInfo = []
    document.getElementById("confirmBtn").addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        author = document.getElementById("author")
        title = document.getElementById("title")
        pages = document.getElementById("pages")
        readStatus = document.getElementById('status') //Line in question
        readStatusInsert = readStatus.options[readStatus.selectedIndex]

        bookInfo[author] = author.value
        bookInfo[title] = title.value
        bookInfo[pages] = pages.value
        bookInfo[readStatusInsert] = readStatusInsert.text
    })
    let newBook = new Book(bookInfo.author, bookInfo.title, bookInfo.pages, bookInfo.readStatusInsert)
    addBooktoLibrary(newBook)
}
```

```css
html{
    height: 100vh;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.header{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 7%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.new{
    margin-left: 5vw;
    
}

.card-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.book{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    border: solid;
    margin: 15px;
}

.buttonDiv{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

input, select{
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="logic.js" defer></script>
    <title>Library</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" defer>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <button class="new">New</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <dialog id="add-dialog">
            <form>
                <label>Add book</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Author" id="author" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="title" required>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Pages" id="pages" min="10">
                <select id="status">
                    <option value="">Select your book status</option>
                    <option value="reading">Reading</option>
                    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
                    <option value="onhold">On-hold</option>
                    <option value="dropped">dropped</option>
                </select>
                <div>
                    <button id='cancel' formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
                    <button id="confirmBtn" type="button" onclick="processInfo()">Confirm</button>
                  </div>
            </form>
        </dialog>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's an online click listener attached to `#confirmBtn`, the handler attaches a new click listener to this same button every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

In arrays, we cannot do that:

```js
bookInfo[author] = author.value
bookInfo[title] = title.value
bookInfo[pages] = pages.value
bookInfo[readStatusInsert] = readStatusInsert.text
```

Instead I recommend putting it an object, then push it

```js
let book = {
  author: author.value
  title: title.value
  pages: page.value
  readStatusInsert: readStatusInsert.text
}
bookInfo.push(book);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in script.js Change this

```
    bookInfo[author] = author.value;
    bookInfo[title] = title.value;
    bookInfo[pages] = pages.value;
    bookInfo[readStatus] = readStatusInsert.text;
```

With:

```
    bookInfo["author"] = author.value;
    bookInfo["title"] = title.value;
    bookInfo["pages"] = pages.value;
    bookInfo["readStatus"] = readStatusInsert.text;
```

In the addBooktoLibrary function, you are pushing the book parameter directly to myLibrary, which isn't recommended. Instead, you should be pushing the book object you've just created. Change this:

```
function addBooktoLibrary(book) {
  myLibrary.push(book);
}
```

To:

```
    function addBooktoLibrary(bookInfo) {
      const newBook = new Book(
        bookInfo.author,
        bookInfo.title,
        bookInfo.pages,
        bookInfo.readStatus
      );
      myLibrary.push(newBook);
    }
```

Now, your processInfo function should only process the form data without the unnecessary event listener:

```
function processInfo() {
  let bookInfo = {};
  author = document.getElementById("author");
  title = document.getElementById("title");
  pages = document.getElementById("pages");
  readStatus = document.getElementById("status");
  readStatusInsert = readStatus.options[readStatus.selectedIndex];

  bookInfo["author"] = author.value;
  bookInfo["title"] = title.value;
  bookInfo["pages"] = pages.value;
  bookInfo["readStatus"] = readStatusInsert.text;

  addBooktoLibrary(bookInfo);
}
```

Make these changes, and your code should work more accurately.

Code should look like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Library</title>
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100vh;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .header {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 7%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .new {
      margin-left: 5vw;
    }

    .card-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .book {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 20%;
      border: solid;
      margin: 15px;
    }

    .buttonDiv {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    form {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    input,
    select {
      margin: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <button class="new">New</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dialog id="add-dialog">
      <form>
        <label>Add book</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Author" id="author" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="title" required />
        <input type="number" placeholder="Pages" id="pages" min="10" />
        <select id="status">
          <option value="">Select your book status</option>
          <option value="reading">Reading</option>
          <option value="completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="onhold">On-hold</option>
          <option value="dropped">dropped</option>
        </select>
        <div>
          <button id="cancel" formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
          <button id="confirmBtn" type="button" onclick="processInfo()">
            Confirm
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </dialog>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container"></div>
  <script>
    let myLibrary = [];

    function Book(author, title, pages, readStatus) {
      this.author = author;
      this.title = title;
      this.pages = pages;
      this.readStatus = readStatus;
    }

    function addBooktoLibrary(bookInfo) {
      const newBook = new Book(
        bookInfo.author,
        bookInfo.title,
        bookInfo.pages,
        bookInfo.readStatus
      );
      myLibrary.push(newBook);
    }

    document.querySelector(".new").addEventListener("click", () => {
      document.getElementById("add-dialog").showModal();
    });

    document.getElementById("cancel").addEventListener("click", () => {
      document.getElementById("add-dialog").close();
    });

    function displayBook(bookInfo) {
      const bookElement = document.createElement("div");
      const buttonDiv = document.createElement("div");
      const removeButton = document.createElement("button");
      removeButton.innerText = "Remove";
      bookElement.innerHTML = `Title: ${bookInfo.title}<br> Author: ${bookInfo.author}<br> Pages: ${bookInfo.pages}<br> Status: ${bookInfo.readStatus}`;
      buttonDiv.appendChild(removeButton);
      buttonDiv.classList.add("buttonDiv");
      bookElement.appendChild(buttonDiv);
      bookElement.classList.add("book");
      removeButton.classList.add("remove");
      document.querySelector(".card-container").appendChild(bookElement);
    }

    function processInfo() {
      let bookInfo = {};
      author = document.getElementById("author");
      title = document.getElementById("title");
      pages = document.getElementById("pages");
      readStatus = document.getElementById("status");
      readStatusInsert = readStatus.options[readStatus.selectedIndex];

      bookInfo["author"] = author.value;
      bookInfo["title"] = title.value;
      bookInfo["pages"] = pages.value;
      bookInfo["readStatus"] = readStatusInsert.text;

      addBooktoLibrary(bookInfo);
      displayBook(bookInfo);
      document.getElementById("add-dialog").close();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

These Are the Best practices ;)

Comment: "_sometimes_"  means very old browser, `defer` works fine if you've decently updated your browsers.

Comment: You can use for also

Comment: The two blocks of code in the beginning [are identical](https://www.diffchecker.com/JObl3HAN/)

Comment: "*In the addBooktoLibrary function, you are pushing the book parameter directly to myLibrary, which isn't recommended.*" why?

Comment: The two blocks of code in the beginning The two blocks of code in the beginning" they are not

Comment: In the addBooktoLibrary function, you are pushing the book parameter directly to myLibrary that is why it isn't recommended it is same but it is not reccomended

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing all the values were being properly fetched, including for the select. However, the `bookInfo` variable was not storing the values correctly.

The indexes for bookinfo were not in strings so they were taking the HTML element variables as the index and that was creating some issues.

Try replacing the code below

```
bookInfo[author] = author.value
bookInfo[title] = title.value
bookInfo[pages] = pages.value
bookInfo[readStatusInsert] = readStatusInsert.text
```

To the following

```
bookInfo['author'] = author.value
bookInfo['title'] = title.value
bookInfo['pages'] = pages.value
bookInfo['readStatusInsert'] = readStatusInsert.text
```

bookInfo is populated correctly post this correction

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be much more dry if you just give the `form` an `id` and the form elements get name attributes instead of ids. Then, you can utilize [the built-in `FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) and [the `FormData: get()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) to get each value.

```js
let myLibrary = [];

function Book(author, title, pages, readStatus) {
  this.author = author
  this.title = title
  this.pages = pages
  this.readStatus = readStatus
}

function addBooktoLibrary(book) {
  myLibrary.push(book)
}

document.querySelector('.new').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('add-dialog').showModal()
})

document.getElementById('cancel').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('add-dialog').close()
})

function displayBook(bookInfo) {
  const bookElement = document.createElement('div');
  const buttonDiv = document.createElement('div')
  const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
  removeButton.innerText = 'Remove'
  bookElement.innerHTML = `Title: ${bookInfo.title}<br> Author: ${bookInfo.author}<br> Pages: ${bookInfo.pages}<br> Status: ${bookInfo.readStatus}`;
  buttonDiv.appendChild(removeButton)
  buttonDiv.classList.add('buttonDiv')
  bookElement.appendChild(buttonDiv)
  bookElement.classList.add('book')
  removeButton.classList.add('remove')
  document.querySelector('.card-container').appendChild(bookElement);
}

//function processInfo(){
document.getElementById("confirmBtn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  const bookForm = document.getElementById("bookForm")
  const bookFormData = new FormData(bookForm)
  const newBook = new Book(bookFormData.get('author'), bookFormData.get('title'), bookFormData.get('pages'), bookFormData.get('status'))

  addBooktoLibrary(newBook)
  displayBook(book)
  bookForm.reset()
})
//}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 7%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.new {
  margin-left: 5vw;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.book {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20%;
  border: solid;
  margin: 15px;
}

.buttonDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input,
select {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="logic.js" defer></script>
  <title>Library</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" defer>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <button class="new">New</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dialog id="add-dialog">
      <form id="bookForm">
        <label>Add book</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Author" name="author" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title" required>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Pages" name="pages" min="10">
        <select name="status">
          <option value="">Select your book status</option>
          <option value="reading">Reading</option>
          <option value="completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="onhold">On-hold</option>
          <option value="dropped">dropped</option>
        </select>
        <div>
          <button id='cancel' formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
          <button id="confirmBtn" type="button">Confirm</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </dialog>
  </div>
  <div class="card-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after debugging for a while, it turns out that there are two problems in my code. The first, as @ pointed out, is that I forgot to add quotation marks around the individual properties of bookInfo that I want to modify. The second one is that I created the book element outside of the Eventlistener. The new book object can't access the properties of bookInfo defined within the scope of the EventListener, hence it gets added into `myLibrary` with all of the properties undefined. Here is how I modify my code to make it work:

```
let myLibrary = [];

function Book(author,title,pages,readStatus) {
    this.author = author
    this.title = title 
    this.pages = pages 
    this.readStatus = readStatus
}

function addBooktoLibrary(book) {
    myLibrary.push(book)
}

document.querySelector('.new').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.getElementById('add-dialog').showModal()
})

document.getElementById('cancel').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.getElementById('add-dialog').close()
}) 


//Add book to display container
function displayBook(bookInfo){
    const bookElement = document.createElement('div');
    const buttonDiv = document.createElement('div')
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.innerText = 'Remove'
    bookElement.innerHTML = `Title: ${bookInfo.title}<br> Author: ${bookInfo.author}<br> Pages: ${bookInfo.pages}<br> Status: ${bookInfo.readStatus}`;
    buttonDiv.appendChild(removeButton)
    buttonDiv.classList.add('buttonDiv')
    bookElement.appendChild(buttonDiv)
    bookElement.classList.add('book')
    removeButton.classList.add('remove')
    document.querySelector('.card-container').appendChild(bookElement);
}

//Reset the dialog after clicking submit
function resetDialog(){
    document.getElementById('author').value = ''
    document.getElementById('title').value = ''
    document.getElementById('pages').value = ''
    readStatus = document.getElementById('status')
    readStatus.value= ""
}

//Fetching book info from submit field
function confirmLibraryBook(Event){
    let bookInfo = []
    author = document.getElementById("author")
    title = document.getElementById("title")
    pages = document.getElementById("pages")
    readStatus = document.getElementById('status')
    readStatusInsert = readStatus.options[readStatus.selectedIndex]

    bookInfo['author'] = author.value
    bookInfo['title'] = title.value
    bookInfo['pages'] = pages.value
    bookInfo['readStatusInsert'] = readStatusInsert.text
    let newBook = new Book(bookInfo.author, bookInfo.title, bookInfo.pages, bookInfo.readStatusInsert)
    addBooktoLibrary(newBook)
    Event.preventDefault()
    document.getElementById('add-dialog').close()
    resetDialog()
    displayBook(newBook)
}

//Initialize logic for Confirm button
function processInfo(){
    document.getElementById("confirmBtn").addEventListener('click', confirmLibraryBook)
    document.getElementById('confirmBtn').addEventListener('click', confirmLibraryBook)
}

processInfo()
```

```
html{
    height: 100vh;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.header{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 7%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.new{
    margin-left: 5vw;
    
}

.card-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.book{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    border: solid;
    margin: 15px;
}

.buttonDiv{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

input, select{
    margin: 5px;
}
```

I essentially rewrote the code for the logic of the confirm button from scratch. When I click the confirm button after having input all of my info, that info will be added into `myLibrary` with `confirmLibraryBook(Event)` and displayed thanks to `displayBook(bookInfo)`.